# how to get data from db before my Express generator app runs?

Tags: node.js, express

i created an app using Express generator. As we know, installing Express generator gives some predefined files of codes that help you run your app within it.

What i want is to fetch some data from db before the app is run but i failed to identify where i should put the code of fetching data from db before the app runs.

Any help?

Comment: Before the app runs or before the generator runs? Can you explain better what you’re going to do with the data you fetch?

Comment: so you want to get the data before the app runs, and then use it when the app runs?

Comment: @ T. Bragg, yes, that is what i want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't know that it was as simple as this:

After installing express generator, follow these steps:

1. Go to bin/www.js and open this file.
2. Put your code of connecting to any db you want after this line:

   var server = http.createServer(app);

   //Put here your code of connecting to any db you want

   server.listen(port);

   server.on('error', onError);

   server.on('listening', onListening);

This has really solved my problem.